# MySQL update converted integer value from varchar value

Tags: mysql

I have MySQL Table column in varchar type as following format

```
+------------+
|   in_num   |
+------------+
| 2020-00821 |
| 2020-00822 |
| 2020-00823 |
| 2020-00824 |
| 2020-00825 |
+------------+
```

I want to select end value to be as interger type from the above column as follows :

```
+--------+
| in_num |
+--------+
|    821 |
|    822 |
|    823 |
|    824 |
|    825 |
+--------+
```

I tried following query

```
select lpad(in_num,5,'0') as in_num from letter
```

But didn't get the desired output. Can anyone help ?

Comment: You would have been better to store that data in 2 seperate columns and your queries would have been so much simpler

Comment: `lpad()` is for adding leading zeroes to a number. It has nothing to do with extracting numbers from a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`SUBSTRING_INDEX()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) to get the part of the string after the `-`. Then cast it to a decimal number.

```
SELECT CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(in_num, '-', -1) AS DECIMAL) AS in_num
FROM letter
```

Answer (score 2):

MySql can do implicit conversion:

```
select right(in_num, 5) + 0 as in_num 
from letter
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/uwxKtkAuCVuMFVTWZhJW8g/0).
Results:

```
| in_num |
| ------ |
| 821    |
| 822    |
| 823    |
| 824    |
| 825    |
```